# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool

Tags: php

no consigo deshacerme de el error mencionado en el titulo, para el tema de conexiones y realizar una query tengo una php externo que contiene una clase.

```
<?php
    /** This PHP file is for connection*/;

    set_error_handler(function() { });
    class db {

        //Variables
            public $error = null;
            private $dbhost = "localhost";
            private $dbuser = "root";
            private $dbname = "inter_project";
            private $dbpassword = "7794CopErnico?";

            public $mySQL;
            private $isConnected = false;         
        //Variables

        public function __construct($autoConnect = false){
            $this->SetDatabase($this->dbname);
            $this->SetServer($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword);

            if($autoConnect){
                return $this->Connect();
            }//end of if
        }//end of the constructor

        public function SetDatabase($dbname){
            $this->dbname = $dbname;
        }

        public function SetServer($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword){
            $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
            $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
            $this->dbpassword = $dbpassword;
        }

        public function Connect(){
            $this->mySQL = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $this->dbname);

            if(empty($this->mySQL->connect_error)){
                $this->isConnected = true;
                return true;
            }else{
                $this->error = $this->mySQL->connect_error;
                return false;
            }//end of the if-else
        }

        public function Close() {
            if(!empty($this->mySQL)){
                if($this->mySQL->close()){
                    $this->isConnected = false;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $this->error = "Couldn't disconnect";
                    return false;
                }//end if-else close
            }else{
                $this->error = "No established connection. Couldn't disconnect";
                return false;
            }//end if-else empty
        }//end of close function

        public function Query($query, $returnAsJSON = false){
            if(!$this->isConnected) {
                $this->error = "No connection established";
                return false;
            }//end of if

            $result = $this->mySQL->query($query);

            if($returnAsJSON) {

                $json = [];
                $json["status"] = $result ? "success" : "failed";
                $json["errorCode"] = $result ? "" : "Wrong Query";

                if($result) {
                    $data = [];
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        $data[] = $row;
                    }//end of while

                    $json["data"] = $data;
                }//end if result
                return json_encode($json);
            }else{
                if($result){

                    return $result;
                }else{

                    $this->error = "Invalid SQL Query";
                    return false;
                }//end if-else
            }//end if-else returnAsJSON
        }//end of query function
    }//end of the class db
?>
```

Estoy realizando una web app con React y PHP , pero como estaba obteniendo continuamente el error mencionado, cree un archivo php aparte para ver si persistía el error y efectivamente, este el código de prueba

```
<?php
    /**File just for test if everything works before using it */
    include_once("../classes/db.php");
    $db = new db(true);
    //include_once('../classes/mysql.php');

    $user="gerroar";
    $object = $db->Query("CALL userExists('$user', true, @isThere)", false);
    if ($object == 1){
        echo "It's true<br/>";
    }

    //He editado esta parte para que se entienda mejor el problema principal
    $result = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM users")->fetch_object;

 
}
?>
```

Entonces esto da como resultado "It's true" y depués

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool in F:\Baaa-Web\FrontEnd\interdisciplinary-project\Backend\auth\tests.php on line 13

Comment: Cambia esto: `if($result == false){` por esto: `if($object == false){` en tu código de prueba para que te muestre bien el error, pues te está devolviendo `false`, o bien cambia esto: `$object = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM users")->fetch_object();` por esto: `$result = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM users")->fetch_object();` para que coincida con la variable del condicional que viene despues

Comment: Ese bloque de codigo que tengo despues es para que accediera al error que tengo asignado en la clase **db**, si coloco `$result = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM users");` si que accede a ese if y me indica el mensaje de error personalizado "Invalid SQL Query", el problema está en que me permite hacer la primera query pero no la segunda.

Comment: Y si te vas al phpmyadmin o lo que tengas para gestionar la base de datos  y haces la consulta directamente te funciona?

Comment: Efectivamente, incluso probé a hacerlo sin la función Query() y funciona, pero es que necesita tener una clase con la conexion y una funcion que realice una query o devuelva un json si o si, entonces no se porque me invalida la segunda query cuando utilizo la funcion Query()

Comment: Y si lo haces con el método clásico, es decir, primero almacenas el resultado de la consulta en una variable y luego le haces un while con el fetch_object, porque entiendo que eso te esta devolviendo todos los usuarios, no solo uno (seguramente te volvera a decir lo del Invalid query, pero es para ir probando y descartando)... o quizas esta tabla no esta en la base de datos **inter_project** y te estás confundiendo

Comment: O cambia esto: `$this->error = "Invalid SQL Query";`  por esto: `$this->error = $this->mySQL->error;` para que te muestre el error completo y veamos mejor de que se trata

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer aquí: `$result = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM users")->fetch_object;`? No estoy seguro de que el encadenamiento de llamadas funcione y aunque lo hiciera, no tiene sentido, porque no se acopla al caso de error..., y por otra parte, ahí faltan los paréntesis para `fetch_object` ¿no?. Para descartar, prueba esto: `$result = $db->Query("SELECT * FROM users"); var_dump($result); var_dump($result->fetch_object());` y dinos qué ves ahora en pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Te está devolviendo `false` la operación `$db->Query("SELECT * FROM users")`.

Presumiblemente por esta parte del código

```
if(!$this->isConnected) {
   $this->error = "No connection established";
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa, pero es que no creo sea eso porque la conexión se realiza sin problemas, me refiero a que la primera query funciona sin problemas por lo que la conexion funciona, sin embargo la segunda ya da error.

Comment: Prueba añadiendo estas lineas al inicio del script php y ejecutar de nuevo a ver que serie de errores aparecen`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
`ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`